# Save content of a text area

Tags: java, text, netbeans, save, area

Hi i'm really new to this world and i was just wondering on how i could save the content of my  jTextArea1 that the next time i open my app, the words that i have typed will be in the text area and the text area won't be empty. What i mean is that i want the textarea to remember all content that is typed inside it because the next time i open the app the content will be inside it and the text area won't be empty. Thanks anyway.

gbp1998

[An image to understand better.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Rk2aukOwOeV1VtbWpqd2N4Vjg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Java persistence is what you need. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html

Comment: You need to persist the data in some way, you can use files , db.

Comment: as @sanket mentioned, you need to your data persistant, i advise to take a look at [Java Serialization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) or, a more used method [JDBC](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-jdbc.html)

Comment: There are variety of different ways of storing the text, eg: in a text file, or in the registry, or in a database. You need to decide first which suits your purposes best.

Comment: @Jurgen i want to be saved on a text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this then to store in a text file:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("area1.txt")));
out.write( jTextArea1.getText() );
out.close();
```